# Why Am I Getting Paypal generic error page in production but not in sandbox

Tags: paypal

Have been successfully using PayPal Cart buttons in PayPal Express for 2 years.  Suddenly, when I click any "Cart button on my Store page, I get the dreaded ""Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

I tried the exact same transaction in the PayPal Sandbox and it processed fine.  Now, however, that transaction draws the generic error page in "Live PayPal"

The only differences in the  are in the action url, the business email, and the return url and store url:

Sandbox version of action attrbute:

```
    <form id="form107" onsubmit="return CheckForm(this);"    
action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self">`
```

Live Version of action attribute:

```
    <form id="form107" onsubmit="return CheckForm(this);"
action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self">
```

(the javascript "CheckForm" function just checks data on the page to determine whether to show or hide a size dropdown)

The Sandbox integration URLs:

```
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:52980/Open/Congratulations/107/store">
<input name="shopping_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:52980/Store">
```

The "Live" integration URLS:

```
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://www.(mydomain).org/Open/Congratulations/107/store">
<input name="shopping_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.(mydomain).org/Store">
```

The code has worked up through 16 April 2018.  No changes were made.  As of 18 April 2018, we are now getting the PayPal generic error page upon clicking the Cart button